# Mac intel (mid-2020) does not charge when plugged in hub, not until the screen is displayed

Tags: charging

The Mac is plugged to a 5K dual HDMI Wavlink, itself plugged to two screens via HDMI switchers. When the Wavlink is started, but the HDMI switch to the HDMI Option 2 (see picture) the Mac does not charge.

I have to switch the display on the HDMI Option 1 (an then I can turn it back top Option 2) to make the power icon appear on the mac.

How can I make the Mac charge from the moment I plug it to the Wavlink ?

[image]